# Can any port in the sate of "LISTEN" be seen to the outter?

Tags: shell, tcp, netstat

I execute the command "netstat -tln" in the shell, here is what it outputs.
[image]

the 5th field is the foreign address, i dont' know what it means here. Does "0.0.0.0:*" mean any address can be connected to this port without the consideration of iptables, if so what does ":::*" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 Colons (:::) signifies IPv6.

The 0.0.0.0 means that a given socket is listening on all the available IP addresses the computer has available.

If you wish to not use IPv6 i believe you can remove it.
Verify the Man Page but probably removing "ipv6.o"" will work.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is IPv4. :::* is IPv6. Both mean 'any available local interface'.